# What is a correct way to compute the discrete derivative of a difference equation?

Tags: finite-differences, discrete-calculus

Consider a discrete map

$x(t+1) = f(x(t)), \quad\forall t\in \mathbb{Z}$

For example, $f(x(t)) = (x(t))^3$.

From searching Wikipedia on forward difference, the discrete equilvalent of the derivative can be a (forward) difference
$\Delta{f(x(t))} = f(x(t+1)) - f(x(t)) = (x(t+1))^3 - (x(t))^3$.

From some online sources (See section 4.1 just below equation (7) from: [http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vered/CourseDS2019/Tutorial%203%20-%201d%20maps.pdf](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Evered/CourseDS2019/Tutorial%203%20-%201d%20maps.pdf)), I can infer that it would be just $3(x(t))^2$.

Which way is correct?

Comment: there might be more than 1 way.

Comment: are you referring to forward, backward, central? I just don’t understand how in the second method it is the same as in continuous derivative.